# EXCEL Cell content based on content in other cell (same row)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I've got a sheet of about 500 entries. This sheet contains 4-letter words in one column, a corresponding number to this row, and a corresponding gender. I need to make a function that finds all rows with the same 4-letter word, then gets a number for males, as well as a number for females. These numbers will then be calculated to an average for males, and a average for females.

Any suggestions? :)

Doesn't have to be one formula for both genders; it can (actually would prefer it to be) one formula for each gender.

Comment: Most likely you need [`COUNTIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/countifs-function-dda3dc6e-f74e-4aee-88bc-aa8c2a866842) function, however it's difficult to tell anything more without knowing your sample data.

Comment: The data is 500 rows, sorted as following:
Score (number)       :       Class (about 20 different options here)       :       Gender (Male/Female).

I need an output as following:
A number, the average, for a certain class and gender. Class and gender I can set manually in each code. 

So basically a 
"if column x, row 1 = class x, then
if column x row 3 = gender male
----> adds number to list that later is calculated into an average score"

Comment: Create pivot table (using pivot table master-builder) with "4-letter words" as rows, "genders" as columns and AVG("numbers") as values. It seems that's all you need.

Comment: This is not sample data, we can't present a solution based on that. Did you tried COUNTIFS as suggested?

Comment: Solved it in another way! Probably not efficient, but it worked (y) Thanks anyways!
For future reference: Used sorting, then just sumproduct for the interval, after which i divided with the size of the interval for an average. Sorry that I couldn't provide Sample Data, reason for that is that it isn't something I'm allowed to share.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In Cell `C8` write this formula & fill down:

=`SUMIFS($B$2:$B$6,$A$2:$A$6,B8,$C$2:$C$6,A8)`

In Cell `C12` write this formula & fill down:

```
 =AVERAGEIF($A$8:$A$10,A12,$C$8:$C$10)
```

**Note,** adjust cell references in formula as needed.